# Why are my SQL subqueries getting syntax errors? Using COUNT()

Tags: sql, subquery

The question is: are there more reviews with the word "love" or with the word "hate" in them?

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(SELECT id FROM review WHERE text LIKE '%love%') FROM review) AS NumLove,
    (COUNT(SELECT id FROM review WHERE text LIKE '%hate%') FROM review) AS NumHate
FROM 
    review
```

Another variation:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(SELECT id FROM review WHERE text LIKE '%love%') AS NumLove,
    COUNT(SELECT id FROM review WHERE text LIKE '%hate%') AS NumHate
FROM 
    review
```

I am getting an error:

> Syntax error near "SELECT"

I have tried to adjust the code a few different times, but I keep getting syntax errors. I can run either of the select statements on their own, and they will execute. I just can't get them to run in a single query.

Comment: Don't count a subquery.  Instead, `select count(*)`.

Comment: But how would I include 2 subqueries?

Comment: Write two different queries.  Doing it in one isn't any faster and harder to read.  (If you had to do it in one you'd have to do subqueries)

Comment: Okay, thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember is functions are used against columns not result sets. Multiple ways to get there. Aside from the CASE example.

```
SELECT COUNT(Pro.Love) AS NumLov
FROM 
(SELECT id Love FROM review WHERE text LIKE '%love%') as Pro
```

To write this in one query, you could use a case expression to turn your love and hate evals into 1 and 0 and use Sum instead of count.

```
SELECT SUM(results.love) AS NumLov
FROM 
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN text like '%love%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS love
  FROM review
) as results
```

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN text LIKE '%love%' THEN 1 END) AS NumLove,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN text LIKE '%hate%' THEN 1 END) AS NumHate
FROM review
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `sum` instead of `count` here when using a condition `case expression` - since you really are adding up (summing) the number of 1s from each `case expression`

```
select 
    Sum(case when text like '%love%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumLove,
    Sum(case when text like '%hate%' then 1 else 0 end) as NumHate
from review
```